# How to treat UnicodeDecodeError: in python smtplib

Tags: python

When running this code:

```
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
    connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=my_rec,
                        msg="subject:New mail\n\nmy nis")
```

I get an error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
All variable have no typos errors.
How to solve?
Thanks

Comment: Please give the complete traceback so we can see which line of code is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg="subject:New mail\n\nmy nis"
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=my_rec,msg.encode("utf-8"))
```